# How to fill a Tuple whit the out of a query select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, tuples

```
    public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetTupleDetailedLog()
    {
        var query = (from c in _context.Lk_business_rules
                     join v in _context.Business_rules_detailed_log on c.User_story_number equals v.User_story_number
                     where c.Status_id_fk == 3
                     group new { c, v } by new { c.Rule_description, c.User_story_number } into cv
                     select new
                     {
                         us = cv.Select(cv => cv.v.User_story_number), //this should be the first int on tuple
                         count = cv.Select(cv => cv.v.Row_id.Count()), //this should be the second int on tuple
                     });
        var TupleList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            TupleList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt32(item.us), Convert.ToInt32(item.count)));
        }
        return TupleList;
    }
```

I have a NEW problem here, I have a list of tuples and I want to fill it with the output of the select of a query. This code is helping me out, but now i have a runtime error:

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { Rule_description = (l.Rule_description), User_story_number = (l.User_story_number) }, ElementSelector:new { c = (EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Lk_business_rules ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: c) IsNullable: False ), v = (EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Business_rules_detailed_log ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: v) IsNullable: False ) } ) .Select(cv => cv.v.User_story_number)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

And:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:

Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

Data involved:

The issue lies in obtaining a tuple with two values ​​to add to an entity that is not mapped with the database.

So, we have on the one hand business rules, which contain their state (we have to filter by state 3) and contain a Rows_id, we have to cross it with the same field in Detailed_log and after grouping by that same field, count how many rows each Row_id has, in detailed_log (What would give us the error that we have to put in the second field of the tuple)

That's why I need the join and group by, and the filter by state in the where.

Comment: Please publish the code of query that is being compiled.

Comment: `cv.Select(cv` - does not compile!

Comment: `Row_id.Count()` - what is `Row_id`? Is it some sequence? Or scalar?

Comment: `.Select(...), //this should be ... int on tuple` - Select returns sequences. It cannot be single number.

Comment: Row_id is VARCHAR(MA) in the database I just figured that :( 
Even so it is filled with numbers, I cannot change the type from the database, can I apply some Convert from the query? I don `t believe

Comment: Your task is easily solved using the `Zip` method. However, it is not possible to give a specific solution until you provide a precise definition of the data involved in the query.

Comment: i will edit the post to explain about the data involved! thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just Select the result of your query into `Tuple<int, int>` instances?

```
return query.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.number, x.count)).ToList();
```

Comment: I will try this! thanks... See my edit, I could already make it work, but now I have a runtime error, maybe it has something to do with the query

Comment: I tried this, the same error... i think the query is the problem, but i dont know other way to solve this, because i need this group by

Comment: It seems like your Select inside the query is flawed. Maybe you want something like `.Select(cv => new { number = cv.Key.User_story_number, /*this should be the first int on tuple*/ count = cv.Count(), /*this should be the second int on tuple*/ });`

Comment: i will try this, i dont know if we can mix query whit linq methods... but i can find a way

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .net Core.  Here's a few ways you can manipulate tuples.  As @kalu93 said, you should be able to create the tuples easily in a select.  In fact in your query you could use the tuple instead of the anonymous type.  Here's some examples of tuples, value tuples, and creating and decomposing both:

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        (int, int)[] intPairs = new (int, int)[] {
            (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)
            };

        List<(int, int)> valueTuples = intPairs.ToList();
        List<(int, int)> valueTuples2 = intPairs.Select(x => (x.Item1, x.Item2)).ToList();
        List<Tuple<int, int>> tuples = intPairs.Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.Item2, x.Item2)).ToList();

        List<Tuple<int, int>> tuples2 = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (var(first,second) in intPairs)
        {
            tuples2.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(first, second));
        }

        List<Tuple<int, int>> tuples3 = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        foreach (var (first, second) in tuples)
        {
            tuples3.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(first, second));
        }

        List<(int, int)> valueTuples3 = new List<(int, int)>();

        foreach (var (first, second) in tuples)
        {
            valueTuples3.Add((first, second));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(valueTuples, valueTuples2));
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(valueTuples, valueTuples3));
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(tuples, tuples2));
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(tuples, tuples3));
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much - I could already make it work, but now I have a runtime error, maybe it has something to do with the query